# Jenkins Multibranch job with declarative pipeline cloning repo for every stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Trying to create a workflow in Jenkins using Declarative Pipeline to do something like this:

1. Checkout the code on 'master'
2. Build solution on 'master' (I know this is not a secure way to do it, but Jenkins is in the intranet so it should be fine for us)
3. Stash artifacts (.dll, .exe, .pdb, etc) => 1st stage
4. Unstash artifacts on nodes depending on what it's needed (Unit tests on a slave, Integration tests on another one and Selenium tests on a another one) => 2nd stage
5. Run tests depending on the slave => 3rd stage running in parallel

The problem that I'm facing is that the git checkout (GitSCM) is executed for every stage.

My pipeline looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label {
            label "master"
            customWorkspace "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\CustomWorkspace"
        }
    }

    options {
        timestamps()
    }

    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            agent {
                label {
                    label "master"
                    customWorkspace "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\CustomWorkspace"
                }
            }
            steps {
                /*
                    steps to build the solution here
                */

                //Sleep because stashing fails otherwise
                script {
                    sleep(1)
                }

                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}\\UnitTests\\bin\\Release") {
                    stash name: 'unit-tests'
                }

                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}\\WebUnitTests\\bin\\x64\\Release") {
                    stash name: 'web-unit-tests'

            }
        }

        stage('Export artefacts') {
            agent {
                label {
                    label "UnitTest"
                    customWorkspace "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\CustomWorkspace"
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Copying dlls from master to ${env.NODE_NAME}"
                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}\\UnitTests\\bin\\Release") {
                    unstash 'unit-tests'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run tests') {
            parallel {
                stage("Run tests #1") {
                    agent {
                        label {
                            label "UnitTest"
                            customWorkspace "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\CustomWorkspace"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        /*
                            run tests here
                        */
                    }
                    post {
                        //post results here
                    }
                }
                //other parallel stages
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, as mentioned earlier, the GitSCM (code checkout) is a part of and performed for every stage:
Build stage
[image]

Export stage
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple simple changes should solve this. You need to tell the pipeline script not to checkout by default every time a node is allocated. Then you need to tell it to do the checkout where you need it:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label {
            label "master"
            customWorkspace "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\CustomWorkspace"
        }
    }

    options {
        timestamps()
        skipDefaultCheckout()      // Don't checkout automatically
    }

    stages {
        stage("Build") {
            agent {
                label {
                    label "master"
                    customWorkspace "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\CustomWorkspace"
                }
            }
            steps {
                checkout scm                      //this will checkout the appropriate commit in this stage
                /*
                    steps to build the solution here
                */

                //Sleep because stashing fails otherwise
                script {
                    sleep(1)
                }

                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}\\UnitTests\\bin\\Release") {
                    stash name: 'unit-tests'
                }

                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}\\WebUnitTests\\bin\\x64\\Release") {
                    stash name: 'web-unit-tests'

            }
        }

        stage('Export artefacts') {
            agent {
                label {
                    label "UnitTest"
                    customWorkspace "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\CustomWorkspace"
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "Copying dlls from master to ${env.NODE_NAME}"
                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}\\UnitTests\\bin\\Release") {
                    unstash 'unit-tests'
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run tests') {
            parallel {
                stage("Run tests #1") {
                    agent {
                        label {
                            label "UnitTest"
                            customWorkspace "C:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\CustomWorkspace"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        /*
                            run tests here
                        */
                    }
                    post {
                        //post results here
                    }
                }
                //other parallel stages
            }
        }
    }
```

I have added 2 lines there. One in the options section (`skipDefaultCheckout()`), and a `checkout scm` in the first stage.